# Selenium: PhantomJS не находит элемент по XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, instagram, автоматизация

Что уж греха таить, живой пример - инстаграм: необходимо добавить комментарий.
В windows7+python3.6.2+selenium+geckodriver ищу элемент (сердечко для "лайка") по XPATH:

```
heart = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "_eszkz _l9yih")]')
```

- находит.

Ищу элемент (строку для добавления комментария) по XPATH:

```
comment = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder = "Add a comment..."]')
```

- находит.

Соответственно, в обоих случаях возвращается массив найденных элементов (на практике в массиве всего 1 элемент), обращаюсь к нему `comment[0].send_keys(comment_text)` и т. д.

В целом, всё работает.

Переношу всё на debian8+python3.4+selenium+**PhantomJS**. Код прежний, ищу элемент (сердечко для "лайка") по XPATH:

```
heart = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "_eszkz _l9yih")]')
```

- находит.

Ищу элемент (строку для добавления комментария) по XPATH:

```
comment = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder = "Add a comment..."]')
```

- **не находит**.

Ставлю `print(len(comment))` - показывает 0. Соответственно, при обращении `comment[0].send_keys(comment_text)` вываливается:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

1) Почему XPATH для "лайка" он находит, а для комментария - нет?

2) Если элемент по XPATH не найден, не должен ли он выбрасывать соответствующее исключение? Почему этого не происходит?

P.S.: Instagram API не предлагать, так как простому юзеру в sandbox'е такого не сделать по причине того, что для получения таких прав (доступ к публичным медиа и работа с ними) необходимо отправить своё приложение на review в ООО/ИП/ЗАО "Instagram", что в моём случае не представляется возможным.

Comment: А если попробовать`comment = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder and @class="_bilrf"]')`?

Answer (score 1):

```
'//textarea[@placeholder = "Добавьте комментарий..."]'
```

Привет! Предположу, что у PhantomJs установлена локализация не ru и содержимое страницы выводится не на русском языке.

Comment: Совершенно верно, моя ошибка - я не указал, просто я копипастил с кода для geckodriver. Соответственно для фантома в оригинале вместо "Добавьте комментарий..." стоит "Add a comment..."

Answer (score 1):

При использовании `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(some_xpath)` selenium находит все элементы подходящие под данный xpath и возвращает список таких элементов.
Если использовать `driver.find_element_by_xpath(some_xpath)` selenium будет искать первый элемент подходящий под данные условия и возвращать его, если же такого элемента не будет найдено, но будет выкинуто `NoSuchElementException`.

Попробуйте следующим образом:
`comment = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder and @class="_bilrf"]')`

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает, результат тот же.

Comment: А если в браузере в консоли  "руками" найти элемент `$x('//textarea[@placeholder = "Add a comment..."]')`? Находит?